# How to represent image label as a vector for MNIST classification with tanh() activator?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, mnist

I'm training fully connected neural network to classify MNIST dataset. Index of the most saturated neuron in the output layer defines network output (digit from 0 to 9).

I would like to use `tanh()` activation function (just for learning purposes).

What is the correct way to represent image label as a vector (for generating  errors vector which will be backpropagated)?

For `sigmoid()` activator this vector could be vector of zeros with only `1` in the position of the classified digit. Does that mean that for `tanh()` it should be vector of `-1`s instead of `0`s (based on range of the function)? What is the general guidance?

Comment: Did you use [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function)?

Comment: @hkchengrex No, I haven't. I have 3 layers (28x28 for input pixels, 30 neurons in hidden layer and 10 neuros in output for each digit). Each layer uses same activation function.

Comment: You should use one since it can represent competition between outputs. If you use plain sigmoid, what should you do when two neurons output '1'? Softmax is kind of like sigmoid but for all channels. It gives the confidence level for each label. I don't think you would still have this question if you use softmax.

Comment: @hkchengrex I have no problem using `tanh()`. Probability that I have two exactly equal activation outputs in `double` is zero so there will be only one "most saturated neuron". My question is about different. How to represent the label as a vector for error calculation. Can you please read again the last paragraph of the Q.? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *have* to use `tanh` in this case, yes you would have make the image labels either -1 or 1. In this case, the 'correct' digit will be pushed to positive infinity and the 'wrong' digit will be pushed to negative infinity.

In general, I would suggest using a `softmax` instead. Their relationship is well explained [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233658/softmax-vs-sigmoid-function-in-logistic-classifier). (`tanh` is just `sigmoid*2-1`). While sigmoid does a binary classification problem (Is this a '7' or is it not), softmax does a multi-class classification (What digit is this most likely to be). The different is that softmax represent the probability distribution across all outputs (if I am very confident that this is a '1', there are lower probabilities that it is a '3' or '4' or others), while multiple independent sigmoid does not care.

In this case, since your output is a one-hot vector, value for each digit is definitely correlated with each other (i.e. a high response from '1' should suppress other responses). Using softmax will make training more stable and give better result.